# node.js save input array from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i want to save input soal and jawaban with radio array form to mongodb
**this my code form ejs**

```
    <% if(soal.length){

        for(var i = 0;i < soal.length;i++) { %>

    <tr>

        <td><%=(i+1)%><input type="hidden" value="<%=soal[i]._id%>" name="soal[i]">
              name="soal" value="<%=soal[i].soal%>" >Soal: <%=soal[i].soal%></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="radio" name="jawaban[<%=i%>]>" valeu="A"><label>A</label>
            <%=soal[i].jawabana%> </input> <br>

            <input type="radio" name="jawaban[<%=i%>]" valeu="B"><label>B</label>
            <%=soal[i].jawabanb%></input> <br>

            <input type="radio" name="jawaban[<%=i%>]" valeu="C"><label>C</label>
            <%=soal[i].jawabanc%></input> <br>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <% }

    }%>
```

but i don't know to save input soal and jawaban with iteration **this my code save**

```
exports.saveujian = function(req, res) {
if (req.session.Siswa){
var ujisave= new Hasilujian({
soal : req.body.soal,
jawaban : req.body.jawaban
}).save(function(err){
    if(err) res.json(err);
    else{   
        res.redirect('/Ujian')
    }
})

}else res.redirect('/');

};
```